# In SQL Server 2005, how to get tables in other databases on which view depends?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2008, for a view in a given database, I can get the tables in other databases on which the view depends by executing:

```
select distinct referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name, referenced_entity_name
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.NameOfView', 'OBJECT')
where referenced_database_name is not null
```

However, `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` is not available in SQL Server 2005. Is there a way to obtain, from the metadata, a list of tables *in other databases* on which a view depends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Aaron Bertrand's [vaguely related blog entry](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008):

> The system table sysdepends does not maintain dependency information
> for any objects located outside of the local database.  This means
> that if you want to check the validity of objects with three- or
> four-part names in SQL Server 2005 or earlier, you are going to have
> to manually parse the definitions of all of your objects.

He goes on to recommend a parser from [here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/a-dependency-checker-you-can-depend-on) - but it's still a nasty job on 2005 I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sys.sql_dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).
It will give you per column dependencies though so you'd have to unique the major id to get the table.

```
select distinct object_name(referenced_major_id)
from sys.sql_dependencies
where object_id = object_id('viewName')
```

As far as getting the results from other databases, that will be tricky as I don't know how the data is stored cross-database and can't test it as I don't have a SQL Server 2005 install readily available to see.  In SQL Server 2008+, the new view is sys.sql_expression_dependencies which is what drives sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities that you mentioned.

I'll do more digging to see if I can figure any more out.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that might be of interest to you. 
Try sp_depends. BOL states that you can derive the dependencies of the view using this sproc in SQL Server 2005. [BOL Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Zhenny, we can achieve this from sqlserver2008+ edition. onwards using below query to list all the objects that are used from the other databases also.

```
select  referenced_entity_name,referenced_database_name
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
where referencing_id = object_id('SCHEMA.OBJECTNAME')
```