# Query to get the information of Databases used by Stored Procedure in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Is there any query in SQL server 2005 that returns the **list of Stored procedures** in the particular database along with the **name of databases** whose objects are getting used in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple thing to do reliably in SQL Server 2005. You might want to look at commercial products such as [ApexSQL Clean](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_clean.aspx) or [SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker/).

In SQL Server 2008 you could try using the [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315(v=sql.100).aspx) dynamic management view. For example,

```
select
    quotename(s.name) + N'.' + quotename(o.name) as ProcedureName,
    ed.referenced_server_name,                                                                                                           
    ed.referenced_database_name,                                                                                                         
    ed.referenced_schema_name,                                                                                                           
    ed.referenced_entity_name                                                                                                           
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies  ed
    inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id = ed.referencing_id
    inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
where
    o.type = 'P'
```

Hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this query is throwing this error "Invalid object name 'sys.sql_expression_dependencies'"

Comment: @HimanshGautam - If you execute `select serverproperty('ProductVersion')` what do you get back?

Comment: That is SQL Server 2005, you tagged your question with SQL Server 2008. The sys.sql_expression_dependencies DMV (and the sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities DMF used by @RezaRahmati) are only available from SQL Server 2008 onwards.

Comment: I am sorry about that , So is there any solution in SQL server 2005?

Answer (score 0):

That is how to get all procedure names:

```
select * 
  from DatabaseName.information_schema.routines 
 where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

I will check now, if there is any way to check their code for table names.

Comment: I am looking for name of databases getting used by the list of SPs

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query

it will show all dependencies even to the columns

```
SELECT      
--SP, View, or Function
ReferencingName = o.name,
ReferencingType = o.type_desc,

--Referenced Field
ref.referenced_database_name, --will be null if the DB is not explicitly called out
ref.referenced_schema_name, --will be null or blank if the DB is not explicitly called out
ref.referenced_entity_name,
ref.referenced_minor_name

FROM sys.objects AS o 
cross apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.' + o.name, 'Object') ref
where o.type = 'p'
-- for other database object types use below line 
-- o.type in ('FN','IF','V','P','TF')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this query is throwing this error "Invalid object name 'sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities'"

Comment: Which version of SQL server you are using?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2005

Comment: @HimanshGautam Unfortunately this object doesn't exists in SQL 2005 and earlier, see the answer of this post for alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922654/in-sql-server-2005-how-to-get-tables-in-other-databases-on-which-view-depends

Answer (score 0):

works for single database

```
select * 
 from information_schema.routines 
 where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```